# Singly Linked List swap not working

Tags: java

I have been trying for some time now to achieve to swap pointers of nodes in a singly Linked List without a lot of success, so any help would be totally acceptable (I have already read and tried to use in my code a lot of answers from previous questions but it seems that I am doing something wrong..)

Here is the code:

```
public void implementation() {
    count = new long[5];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        count[i] = count2++;
    }

    Link[] nodeList2 = LinkList.Insert_Link(count,count.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.length - 1; i++) {
        nodeList2[i].next = nodeList2[i + 1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.length -  1; i += 2) {
        LinkList.Swap_Node_Pointers(nodeList2[i], nodeList2[i + 1]);
    }

    // LinkList.Swap_Node_Pointers(nodeList2[1], nodeList2[1 + 1]);

    LinkList.display(nodeList2);       
}
```

And the code of the Insert, Swap_Node_Points and display is:

```
public Link[] Insert_Link(long[] value, int countlength) {        
    final Link[] nodeList = new Link[countlength] ;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {    
        nodeList[i] = new Link();
        nodeList[i].value2 = value[i];
    }

    return nodeList;
}

public void display(Link[] b) {
    Link[] nodeList2 = b;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.length; i++) {            
        System.out.println("The value is" +nodeList2[i].value2);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public void Swap_Node_Values(final Link n1, final Link n2) {  
    long value; 
    // Link temp = null;

    value = n1.value2;
    n1.value2 = n2.value2;
    n2.value2 = value;
}

public void Swap_Node_Pointers(Link n1, Link n2) {      
    Link temp =  n1.next;     
    n1.next = n2.next;
    n2.next = temp;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the final thing you want to achieve? Also, I find this code incomplete.

Comment: This is just part of the full code, but what i do in this part is entering the values into the nodeList and then i just want to swap the pointers and display the values. ( of course the problem is that it does not swap them ).

Comment: It always helps to make a little drawing with the nodes and links and to update the drawing as you go step by step through the statements in your methods. You are also using a lot of arrays, that is not the idea of a linked list. A typical linked list implementation does not use any arrays.

Comment: Thanks :) I will try to take out the arrays, i have just used them cause it seemed easier to be honest.. Any idea why the swap pointers is not working?

Comment: Frankly, no. I don't want to discourage you but your current code is a bit too confusing to understand what it does in reasonable time. Give it a fresh start.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping (pointers of) nodes in a linked list doesn't make any sense. You should just swap (pointers of) value objects (like you are actually doing in your code). I would start by designing interface before writing the actual implementation.

Because performance difference between a singly and doubly linked lists are abysmal in Java, I would use default LinkedList implementation. That said, I wrote you interfaces/classes that you could use to accomplish your task:

```
public class ValueHolder<T> {
  private T value;

  public ValueHolder(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public T getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public void swap(ValueHolder<T> valueHolder) {
    T temp = getValue();
    setValue(valueHolder.getValue());
    valueHolder.setValue(temp);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getValue() != null ? getValue().toString() : null;
  }
}

public interface SinglyLinkedList<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  public void add(T value);
}

public class SystemOutPrinter {
   public <T> void print(Iterable<T> iterable) {
      Iterator<T> it = iterable.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println("Value: " + it.next());
      }
   }
}

...

// ValueHolders contain the actual values
ValueHolder<MyObject> vh1 = new ObjectValueHolder<MyObject>(obj1);
ValueHolder<MyObject> vh2 = new ObjectValueHolder<MyObject>(obj2);
// Create list
SinglyLinkedList<ValueHolder<MyObject>> list = new DefaultSinglyLinkedList<ValueHolder<MyObject>>();
// Add valueHolders to list
list.add(vh1);
list.add(vh2);
// Print
new SystemOutPrinter().print(list);
// Swap
vh1.swap(vh2);
// Print
new SystemOutPrinter().print(list);
```